# What application is this (screen shot) gvim + addons?

Tags: vim

I found this screen shot on a Github project, and I'd really like to give that editor a try:
https://github.com/nicklasos/numix-molokai/blob/master/numix-molokai.png

I assumed it was gvim, but the gvim I've installed (package gnome-vim) Looks very little like that application.

Am I just missing some configuration, or vim addons to get there?

Comment: Hahaha, ticking the incorrect and incomplete answer because the correct and complete one rubbed you in the wrong way. Beautiful!

Comment: Dukiboto answered first and got me all I needed to know. Powerline looks like a super cool project, though I've been having trouble using the bash bindings and changing directory. And I still can't figure out how to turn Nerdtree on in vim (Or powerline for that matter). I'm not sure I'll ever actually get into vim as a primary ide but I'm super glad id exists for the quick server=side changes.

Comment: ^ Found the key binding for nerdtree, its F2 with nicklasos's config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's gvim with a few plugins (Nerdtree, powerline)

Answer (score 6):

First, your answer:

It's GVim, obviously, with the molokai colorscheme, obviously, Airline for the stupid fancy statusline, NERDTree for the file explorer and Tabline for the tab line replacement.

Second, a comment:

You can find the answer in that person's [dotvim](https://github.com/nicklasos/dotvim) repository but you didn't even try to find the answer yourself before requesting the help of the whole internet.

Try a little harder, next time.